# Understanding function literal types

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, functional-programming

Assuming this code:

```
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val func = (x: String, y :String) => x + ", " + y
    println(myFunc(func))
  }

  def myFunc(f: (String, String) => String) = {
    f("Hey","how are you?")
  }
```

The second line of this code is replaced by compiler to:

```
val func = new Function2[String, String, String] {
             def apply(x: String, y: String): String = x + ", " + y
           }
```

I can deduce that `func` type in this case corresponds also to `(String, String) => String)` type, as the `myFunc` signature shows; meaning that `Function2[String, String, String]` is the same type as `(String, String) => String`.

Why different notations? Why Scala compiler hasn't rather transformed the function literal to some kind of conceptual: `new ((String, String) => String)` without boring with `Function2[String, String, String]` type? Or vice versa.

One explanation would be that a class name cannot be multipart as: `(T1, T2) => R`.
But why not after all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why Scala compiler hasn't rather transformed the function literal to some kind of conceptual: `new (String, String) => String`

Remember that Scala compiles down to JVM bytecode. There is no such thing as "*conceptual`new (String, String) => String`*" in JVM. There are only objects and methods (at least until Java 8). In Java language you have to use boring `Callable<T>`, `Runnable` or various `Function` abstractions in Guava and Apache Commons. There is no way around it. From that perspective Scala basically hides Java boilerplate by adding syntactic sugar over anonymous `FunctionX[...]` classes.

That's also one of the reasons why Scala compiler has to do so much fiddling when you use a method where function was expected (so called *eta expansion*).

Comment: It might be interesting to have a comment on how Scala plans (if so) adapt Java 8 features for underlying definition of functions

Comment: @om-nom-nom: Indeed. Unfortunately not only I don't know how will Scala benefit from lambdas in Java 8, I don't even know how will they be implemented in Java 8...

Comment: Actually, Scala's support for first-class functions is the *exact* same as Java's: they are just objects which respond to a single method. The difference is mainly that there is a standardized name (`apply`) for that method and that there is a library of classes (`FunctionN`) and methods (`map`, …) readily provided. And of course the syntax sugar makes a *huge* difference. Lambdas in Java 8 are more or less the same as in Scala. The main difference is that they don't expand to a predefined `FunctionN.apply`, but rather to *any* Single-Abstract-Method interface, because there's so much of them

Comment: already existing in the libraries, like `Callable`, `Runnable`, `Comparator`, etc.

Comment: In other words: Lambdas are purely a Java language feature. They don't have any effect on Scala at all, except indirectly: convenient syntax for SAM interfaces will mean that there will be more of them in the libraries in the future, which means that instead of having to write full wrappers for Java libraries, you can get by with a couple of implicit conversions back and forth between that specific library's SAM interfaces and Scala's `FunctionN` interfaces.

Comment: What *will* have a big impact on Scala *performance* is when Scala drops support for the Java 5 platform and can use `MethodHandle`s and `invokedynamic` for first-class functions and even more importantly for method dispatch on structural types (which is currently extremely expensive because it is implemented with reflection).